# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build XXXXXXXXXXXXXX status: FAILURE

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform

Details logs in bitbucket pipeline:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build bf2dea28-ba60-4951-9dbf-7d3575f25328 status: FAILURE.
Build error details: Build error details not available..
```

When check the logs in GCP build console, got below error:

```
Step #5 - "builder": Executing command "npm ci --quiet --production"
Step #5 - "builder": npm ERR! cipm can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
Step #5 - "builder": npm ERR! 
Step #5 - "builder": npm ERR! 
Step #5 - "builder": npm ERR! Missing: dateformat@^3.0.3
Step #5 - "builder": npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's query-string@4.3.4 does not satisfy query-string@^6.10.1
Step #5 - "builder": npm ERR! Missing: rc-datepicker@^5.0.15
Step #5 - "builder": npm ERR! Missing: react-accessible-accordion@^3.0.1
Step #5 - "builder": npm ERR! Missing: react-year-picker@^0.3.7
Step #5 - "builder": npm ERR! Missing: react-stepper-horizontal@^1.0.11
Step #5 - "builder": npm ERR! Missing: react-idle-timer@^4.2.12
Step #5 - "builder": npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's react-toastify@5.1.0 does not satisfy react-toastify@^5.5.0
Step #5 - "builder": npm ERR! Missing: recharts@^2.0.0-beta.1
Step #5 - "builder": npm ERR! 
Step #5 - "builder": 
Step #5 - "builder": npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Step #5 - "builder": npm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2020-04-18T20_44_32_131Z-debug.log
```

Note: Able to deploy the node (react) application since two months. Suddenly getting this error for past two days.

Comment: its in production mode. No need to worry about dev dependencies and package-lock.json.

Comment: Worry why all of sudden

Comment: Hi, have you tried to run `npm install` as indicated in the error? Could you also include the complete log created under /builder/home/.npm/...